# how to change a part in multiple filenames from 1 to 01?

Tags: regex, linux, sed, file-rename

I have lots of files in a directory.

Example:

```
 "/data/2014/file300.data.20141231.MC.9.vgf.img"
```

here `9` represent the hour and change from `1 to 24`,the date also change.
the hours are represented `.1.  .2. .3. .4.   .... .9.`
I want to replace this part(only this part) in the file name with `.01.  .02. .03. .04.   .... .09.`  and do not touch any other number in the file name.

so .1. become .01.  and so on

Comment: Use `rename` to rename files with a regex.

Comment: Please add the name of your distribution and its version number as text to your question.

Comment: See: [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution#Popular_distributions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with Larry Wall's `rename` to replace `.MC.` by `.MC.0`:

```
rename 's/\.MC\./.MC.0/' /data/2014/*.img
```

Comment: `'s/\.MC\./.MC.0/'` is a Perl expression. There are at least two implementations of `rename` out there. For this reason I mentioned the [author](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Wall).

Comment: With bash: `for i in /data/2014/file*.img; do [[ $i =~ (.*\.)([0-9]\.vgf.img) ]] && echo mv -v "$i" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}0${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"; done`. If everything looks okay, remove `echo`.

Comment: `rename` is a standalone perl program. Use it without prefix `perl`. Try `which rename` to check if `rename` is in your path. And try `man rename`.

Comment: Please start a new question and mention that you want to use Larry Wall's `rename`. Thank you.