# How to replace a number in a file name but subtract 1 from it?

Tags: regex, linux, sed, rename

I have lots of files in a directory (Linux). For example:

```
"/data/2014/file300.data.20141231.MC.0930.vgf.img"
```

Here 0930 represents the hour and change from 1 to 24 (30 does not change), the date also changes. The hours are represented as

```
   .0130.  .0230. .0330. .0430.   ...2330... ...2430.
```

I want to replace this part (only this part) in the file name by subtracting the hour by 1

```
  .0030.  .0130. .0230. .0330.   ... .2230.
```

and do not touch any other number in the file name. So

- .0130. becomes .0030.
- .0230. becomes .0130.

and so on

```
2430. becomes .2330.
```

I tried this:

```
 rename -n 's/(\d+)(\.vgf.img)/($1-1).$2/e' file300.data.20141231.MC.0930.vgf.img
```

but it returned this:

```
file300.data.20141231.MC.929.vgf.img
```

so `.0930.` became `.929.` which is not what I am looking for. I'm looking for `.0830.`

Comment: Quite similar to your previous [how to change a part in multiple filenames from 1 to 01?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31525621/1983854). May be good to show your attempts based on the good solution by Cyrus

Comment: Regular Expressions are a method for finding patterns within strings, they don't really know about numbers (beyond the fact that are a limited subset of characters that can appear in a string). Similarly, SED also works with strings. You will probably need to look at [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) as a mechanism for providing some additional user-defined functions that can handle the subtraction for you - there's nothing in regular expressions that will do that.

Answer (score 3):

Regular Expressions are not great for such a task, and it would be easier to use awk or a perl script. However, you can still do it in sed if you really want! =)

There is no trivial way of decrementing number in sed, but you can emulate it:

```
#!/bin/sed -f
# Replace number XX from line
# "/data/2014/file300.data.20141231.MC.XX30.vgf.img"
# with decremented number (XX-1)
# zero is not changed

# copy filename to hold space
h
# remove everything that is not a number
s/.*MC\.//
s/30\.vgf.*//
# ensure that we don't have leading zeroes
s/^0*//

# here all the magic begins, decrementing

# we need to move all trailing zeroes to begin of number
# we do it using cycle:

# clear test condition
t b
: b
# if we have zero - move it
/0$/{
  # remove from end
  s/0$//
  # append to begin
  s/^/0/
}
# if substitution was made - continue cycle
t b

# now we have nonzero at the end, decrement it
s/1$/0/
s/2$/1/
s/3$/2/
s/4$/3/
s/5$/4/
s/6$/5/
s/7$/6/
s/8$/7/
s/9$/8/

# here we change number of digits in our number, this needs to be done only 
# when number was of type 10*, in that case after all our permutations it is 
# represented as line of all zeroes - just remove one.
/^0*$/s/0//

# another cycle to put zeroes back at end
t e
: e
/^0/{
  # remove from beginning
  s/^0//
  # add to end, as 9
  s/$/9/
}
t e
# Now we have decremented number in pattern space and original filename in hold
# format number as two-digit:
s/^$/00/
s/^.$/0&/
# append it to hold space
H
# switch hold and pattern 
x
# now we manipulate string like "$filename\nXX" where XX is our decremented
# number.
# Replace number in filename with decremented one
s/\(.*MC\.\)..\(30.*\).\(..\)/\1\3\2/
```

Comment: @Barry my answer can solve your problem, but I would not use it myself. Instead I would use something more practical like: `for filename in *.vgf.img; do new=\`echo $filename| perl -e '$_=<>;/(.*)(..)(30\.vgf\.img)/;printf "$1%02d$3", $2-1'\`; mv $filename $new; done;` which utilizes perl. Or use some other language that can operate on numbers properly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to subtract 100 instead of 1 to get 830 from 930. Then to format the result with leading zeros you can use [`sprintf`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html). The below command will work as expected

```
~$ rename -n 's/(\d+)(\.vgf.img)/(sprintf("%04d", ($1 - 100))).$2/e' file300.data.20141231.MC.0930.vgf.img
rename(file300.data.20141231.MC.0930.vgf.img, file300.data.20141231.MC.0830.vgf.img)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had initially written this as a somewhat tongue-in-cheek response and did not intend to post, but seeing Yury's solution (which is brilliant!) I feel compelled to give this as at least potentially usable.

You haven't specified the problem adequately, but assuming that your files all have the ending "${timestamp}.vgf.img" (really, just assuming the existence of two dots in the name after the timestamp):

```
 echo /data/2014/file300.data.20141231.MC.0930.vgf.img |
      awk '{a=substr($(NF-2),0,2); $(NF-2)=(a-1)"30"} 1' FS=. OFS=.
```

Comment: You can use sprintf: ` awk '{a=substr($(NF-2),0,2); $(NF-2)=sprintf("%02d",(a-1))"30"} 1' FS=. OFS=.`  And you'll need to capture the output and use `mv` to actually rename the file.  eg `newname=$( echo $oldname | awk ...); mv $oldname $newname`, but that is beyond the scope of this question.